# Managing Node JS dependencies

Tags: node.js

I am learning node js and I have put together a small website which is using a few dependencies like jquery and a couple of other js files. When it comes to moving the site to a live server how do I migrate the dependencies that I used in production? Would I have to download the jquery files and other js library files then add the link into my script tags like you normally would as I guess everything in production points at the node_modules folder?

Sorry for sounding a little daft but I’m still learning my way with npm.

Appreciate any advice
Rufus

Comment: Are you talking about server application dependencies or client application dependencies? You're mixing them together, while they can be treated independently. jQuery is client dependency. It doesn't have anything to do with Node, except that it can be installed with NPM (but not necessarily should).

Comment: To be honest I’m getting myself a little bit confused I think.  I am mainly looking at client dependencies, I see a lot of js plug-ins now that have links to install via npm. What I am trying to understand is once I have a node js package installed how do I then go about referencing this js file when I move everything to the live server for production as I won’t be copying over the npm modules folder where it currently points to. Hope that kinda makes sense apologies if not

Comment: your production server should run some sort of build process, namely `npm install` which will install all the npm packages again.

Answer (score 0):

In Node.js, server side dependencies are saved in the package.json file and these describe any dependencies you'll need.

You create this file by typing

```
npm init
```

This will prompt you for some details (which you can skip with -y flag.)

To install your server side dependencies, I presume you've used:

```
npm install <dependency>
```

To ensure this is saved you can type

```
npm install <dependency> --save
```

e.g.

```
npm install lodash --save
```

This will update your package.json.

package.json should be stored in source control and your dependencies can be restored using:

```
npm install.
```

An example of a package.json file would look like this:

```
{
  "name": "node_test_project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.11"
  }
}
```

If you see a package-lock.json file (later versions of NPM), this should be added to source control too.

Comment: Thanks for this, everything you have mentioned is the exact process I followed when setting up my first package. I am mainly using npm for sass but thought I would dabble with a few js plugins that can be installed this way. I just don’t understand how I then move all of this from testing to my live web server

Comment: Normally you'd wrap all this up in a script, say bash, something like setup.sh, which will call npm install in the same dir as your node project. You should only need to upload say your index.js, package.json and script file for this purpose! Once your files are present on a server you'd run the setup script and it should install your dependencies.

Comment: Of course, you'd need npm and node.js to be present on the server too!

Answer (score 0):

Personally I just use `npm install lodash`

Then

```
app.use('/scripts/lodash', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/lodash/'));
```

that way I can use this as (in node.js)

```
const _ = require('lodash');
```

or in an html file as

```
<script src='/scripts/lodash/lodash.js'></script>
```

Preventing the whole "copying to public/js"...

Or if you're just talking about a build process, you just run `npm install` on your productions server and it installs all the packages from `packages.json` again.